# when the iterable is NOT the first argument of the function

Tags: r, apply, sapply

The problem is quite simple yet I can't find the answer.

I have `myfun <- function(x, y)`. How can I `sapply` this function over a list of `y`?

To apply over `x` I would do this

```
iterables <- 1:10
sapply(iterables, myfun, y)
```

But I want the iterables to be y instead.

Comment: Do you look for `sapply(y, myfun, x=x)`?

Comment: In reality, my function has more than 2 arguments though. I can't specify all the other arguments by hand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several options - e.g. one mentioned by sgibb which relies on how R interprets function arguments, i.e. that `myfun(y, x = x)` is the same as `myfun(x, y)`.

I prefer creating anonymous functions since it's easier to understand what's happening:

```
sapply(iterables, function(iter) myfun(x, iter))
```

Comment: If `myfun` has, say, 5 arguments, can I do this? `sapply(iterables, function(iter) myfun(x1, x2, x3, iter, x4)`?